# How to like a facebook post by Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

Im using this method to like a post, the problem is that im always getting a NullPointer as Facebook Response. Whey is it happening?

EDIT: This is the method im using right now...same shit happening.

```
public void likePost (final Bundle params){

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
          SessionState state = session.getState();

          if (state.isOpened()){

                if (session.isPublishPermission("publish_stream")){

                    Request likeRequest = new Request(session, params.getString("object")+ "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                     @Override
                     public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Log.i("LIKE_METHOD", response.toString());
                     }
                        });
                        Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
                }else {

                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_stream")));

                    Request likeRequest = new Request(session, params.getString("object")+ "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                         @Override
                         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                Log.i("LIKE_METHOD", response.toString());
                         }
                            });
                            Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);

                }

            }

        }
        else {
           Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                    if (state.isOpened()){

                        if (session.isPublishPermission("publish_stream")){

                            Request likeRequest = new Request(session, params.getString("object")+ "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                             @Override
                             public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    Log.i("LIKE_METHOD", response.toString());
                             }
                                });
                                Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
                        }else {

                            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(getParent(), Arrays.asList("publish_stream")));

                            Request likeRequest = new Request(session, params.getString("object")+ "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                                 @Override
                                 public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                        Log.i("LIKE_METHOD", response.toString());
                                 }
                                    });
                                    Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);

                        }

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the response from the method:

> 03-06 15:55:08.532: D/LIKE_METHOD(16686): {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: java.lang.NullPointerException}, isFromCache:false}
>   pe: null, errorMessage: java.lang.NullPointerException}, isFromCache:false}

Comment: Does the facebook API tell you there will be a response returned? Add your stacktrace. Also, edit this post to tell us which lines are which so we can help you out better.

Comment: Okay, so the response is 200, which means success. The error object is null, which seems fine since it doesn't look like there was an error. Can go to the 'liked' page and see if it was indeed 'liked' ?

Comment: Yeah...i went to the page and it was not liked. :/

Comment: I have to use "id" or "object_id", from json, to like?

Comment: @WitaloBenicio: Can you try and move this part `final Session sess = session;
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest((Postagens)context, Arrays.asList("publish_stream")));` out of the `likePost()` method? Call the statement for the `publish_stream` permission before calling the `likePost()` method and see if that works.

Comment: Code updated, but still not working. Im using "object_id" returned by json.